# DIV onClick in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

For the title of my website, I have the following code with a DIV onclick so that the user can click anywhere on the title and refresh the page:

```
<div class="title" onClick="document.location.href='xxxx';">
```

However the W3C validator tells me this:

> there is no attribute "onClick"

I've read about doing this in jQuery, but I've not had much luck getting that work. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks

Comment: That's the **W3C** validator.  http://w3fools.com

Comment: Ha, my mistake. I did not know they were not associated. I will have to spread the word!

Comment: This page doesn't help that situation http://www.w3schools.com/site/site_validate.asp

Comment: Personally, I strongly recommend you use the jQuery way of attaching your click handler instead of explicitly putting it in your `onclick=` markup. Separation of behavior, and all that jazz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` should be lowercase.

Comment: Ah excellent! I didn't even notice I'd done it in caps! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".title").click(function(){
    document.location.href='xxxx';
}):
```

Comment: Have tried that already, it doesn't seem to call the function :(

Comment: Maybe that's 'cause this is calling `#title`, not `.title`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the options.

```
<div class="title" onclick="javascript:reloadPage();">

function reloadPage()
{
   window.location.reload();
}
```

or

```
<div  class="title"  onclick="window.location.href=window.location.href">
```

or

```
$(".title").click(function(){
    document.location.reload();
}):
```